# How to specify rvm gemsets for Rails gem whenever?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, cron, rvm, whenever

MyApp is using rvm gemset 1.9.3@rails-3.2. It is not default.

I am using gem 'whenever' to periodically send email notifications. This is my schedule.rb:

```
every 1.minutes do
 runner "MyModel.send_emails" # if ... 
end
```

Cron job is not working unless gemset 1.9.3@rails-3.2 is default. How can i improve my schedule.rb in order to use another gemsets (not only default @global) for my scheduller.

I have read official documentation: [whenever](https://github.com/javan/whenever) and [rvm issues](https://github.com/javan/whenever/wiki/RVM-Notes) and stackoverflow questions about "rvm gemsets for whenever", but have not found an answer.

I have tried to put the following code (according to advice in RVM-Notes) in my shedule.rb:

```
job_type :runner, "{ cd #{@current_path} > /home/####/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@
rails-3.2/bin/rails; } && RAILS_ENV=:environment bundle exec rails runner ':task' :output"
```

but it gives no result:

```
ERROR: 
/home/###/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/gems/bundler-1.3.5/lib/bundler/spec_set.rb:92
:in `block in materialize': Could not find i18n-0.6.5 in any of the sources
(Bundler::GemNotFound)
```

How to specify rvm gemsets for Rails gem 'whenever'? Many thanks!

**UPDATE**

1) I have tried to provide rvm notaions for my Gemfile like this:

```
ruby=ruby-1.9.3-p448 # with # sign

ruby-gemset=rails-3.2 # with # sign
```

It gives no result. Nothing changes.

2) I have tried to modify my ~/.rvmrc. Experiments with full path to bundle, rails gives me the following list of errors:

```
    /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
    /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory
    /bin/bash: bundle: command not found
    /bin/bash: bundle: command not found
    /usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks/usr/bin/env: ruby_executable_hooks: No such file or directory
   : No such file or directory
```

Here by job_type experiments:

```
#job_type :runner, "{ cd #{path}; } && RAILS_ENV=:environment bundle exec rails runner ':task' :output"
 job_type :runner, "{ cd #{path}; } && RAILS_ENV=:environment /home/###/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/bundle exec rails runner ':task' :output"
#job_type :runner, "cd #{path} && RAILS_ENV=development /home/###/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@global/bin/bundle exec /home/###/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails-3.2/bin/rails runner ':task' :output"
```

Comment: did you happen to try rvmrc??

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use wrapper:

```
job_type :runner, "cd #{path} && RAILS_ENV=development /home/###/.rvm/wrappers/ruby-1.9.3-p448@rails-3.2/bundle exec rails runner ':task' :output"
```

this will load proper rvm environment and run `bundle` in its context, bundler only adds environment variables for using gems from `Gemfile` without modifying the loaded ruby environment.

a similar situation is described here http://rvm.io/integration/init-d

Comment: Thank you, I have no errors in my shedule log. Very useful link

Answer (score 1):

try

```
job_type :runner, "cd :path && RAILS_ENV=:environment bundle exec rails runner :task :output"
```

Assuming you have mentioned in `Gemfile`

```
#ruby=ruby-1.9.3-p448
#ruby-gemset=rails-3.2
```

See [RVM Documentation](http://rvm.io/workflow/projects#project-file-gemfile) for this notation

Comment: I have done this, but have got error in my log: /bin/bash: bundle: command not found. All is working fine if my gemset is default

Comment: use full path for bundler

Answer (score 0):

Try to create .rvmrc file in your project root directory and have the following line

```
rvm use 1.9.3@rails-3.2
```

Comment: I have try it, but have error message in my whenever log: /bin/bash: bundle: command not found

Comment: If I comment line job_type :runner mentioned above, I have got the folliwing error in my log: /usr/bin/env: ruby: No such file or directory